# Relplace str in list with n many strings starting from 0

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for-loop

Given a list of lists and an integer, I need to replace every string with n many string.
Where n = integer given. 
Ex.:

```
irv_to_stv_ballot([['NDP', 'CPC'], ['GREEN']], 3)
[['NDP0', 'NDP1', 'NDP2', 'CPC0', 'CPC1', 'CPC2'], ['GREEN0', 'GREEN1', 'GREEN2']]
```

Comment: And what have you tried ? And it seems you're appending, not replacing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `loops` or `list comprehension` : for each word of each sublist, concat with digit from 0 to the limit :

```
def irv_to_stv_ballot(values, count):
    return [[word + str(digit) for word in value for digit in range(count)] for value in values]


def irv_to_stv_ballot(values, count):
    result = []
    for value in values:
        inner_res = []
        for word in value:
            for count in range(count):
                inner_res.append(word + str(count))
        result.append(inner_res)
    return result
```

Comment: The first function ended up working! The second one yielded a slightly different result. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @MatthewTabet really ? I got absolutly the same

Answer (score 1):

Here's a variation that employs a lambda:

```
def replace(items: list, value: int) -> list:
    """takes a list of lists of strings and an int"""
    func = lambda x, y: x + str(y)
    for i, sublist in enumerate(items):
        tempA = []
        for sequence in sublist:
            tempB = [func(sequence, x) for x in range(value)]
            tempA.extend(tempB)
        items[i] = tempA
    return items
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `itertools.repeat` with `enumerate()` as well:

```
from itertools import repeat


def irv_to_stv_ballot(values, count):
    return [
        ["%s%d" % (e, i) for item in value for i, e in enumerate(repeat(item, count))]
        for value in values
    ]


print(irv_to_stv_ballot([["NDP", "CPC"], ["GREEN"]], 3))
```

Output:

```
[['NDP0', 'NDP1', 'NDP2', 'CPC0', 'CPC1', 'CPC2'], ['GREEN0', 'GREEN1', 'GREEN2']]
```